# convert ranking to points value

Tags: ranking

I am trying to take several 'ranking' lists add weighted values and come up with a net score to compare.
Take the PGA tour players.  I would like to take putting, driving and chipping and convert rank to a score.  two issues:

1. How do I covert rank to a value that I can then assign a weight to?  i.e. I think putting is 2x the other two. so `score= 2P+D+C`
   if I use the raw data, my formula doesn't work (lower score is better so multiplying hurts it)
2. if i use simple `math newP=(100-P)` where `P` was the players ranking & `newP` is their Putting Score...I think it over simplifies it.  #1 ranked putter gets 99 point, #2 gets 98  etc

so I need a) how to convert rank (lowest to highest) to a points system (highest to lowest) & b) any thoughts on nuancing the ranking to give higher weight to the highest ranking players.  (so the order values are not linear)

Answer (score 1):

As to Part a) of your question, I attached a clip from an Excel spreadsheet showing one method for converting a ranking system, which identifies better performance with smaller numbers, to a points system, which uses larger numbers to label better performance.

The exhibit uses the Putting ranking from the PGA website [https://www.pgatour.com/stats/stat.159.html].

The formulas shown in the exhibit, are written without spaces between the characters.

As to Part b), you may want to run all the categories (P, C, D) before weighting any particular quantity. Also, consider applying a number for tournament wins, maybe multiply the (P+C+D) result by the ratio 
Wins / Tournaments Played or 
(P + C + D) X (Wins/Tournaments Played) = Overall Points.

[image: Excel Example]